# XHR Response with For-Loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this issue with my XMLHttpRequest that I'm making. The idea is that the loop is mean to loop through a JSON array of users and also load their profile image. Loading the users works absolutely fine but when I loop to get the profile image, it shows it with the last user.

I can see where the issue lies but I don't know how to solve it. When I debug this, it does not run the xhr[i].onload part, which is important because I'm trying to append the image found to the id of the user as the loop runs. The first part of the loop will create the 'img id ="username"' for the username and then i want the XHR request to run and get the image and then append it to the 'img id' tag.

```
function parseJSON() {
console.log(jsonArrayOfUsers);
var htmlStart = '<ul class ="softwares">';
var htmlEnd = '</ul>'
var html = ''
var len = jsonArrayOfUsers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var xhr = [];
    currentuser = jsonArrayOfUsers[i].username;
    currentavatar = jsonArrayOfUsers[i].avatar
    console.log(currentuser);

    html += '<li class ="softwares">' 
            + '<p><img id ="' + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].username + '" width="auto" height="100px"/></p>'
            + '<p>' + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].fullName + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].username + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].university + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].userType + '</p></li>';

            (function (i){
                if (jsonArrayOfUsers[i].avatar == null){}
                else{
            xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr[i].open("GET", "URL TO API" + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].avatar, true);
            xhr[i].setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.token);
            xhr[i].responseType = 'blob';
            xhr[i].onload = function response(e) {
                               var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                               imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);   
                               document.querySelector("#" + currentuser).src = imageUrl;
                            };
            xhr[i].send();
            }})(i);

}
var htmlFull = htmlStart + html + htmlEnd
$('.people').append(htmlFull);
```

Comment: `currentuser` is a global variable, so `document.querySelector("#" + currentuser)` will refer to the same element when the `onload` function fires, which will be after the `for` loop finishes. You’re already handling the variable `i` correctly. Use the very same IIFE to put `currentuser` (etc.) as an additional parameter and argument there.

Comment: That worked! Ahhh thank you soooo much! All I did was change currentuser to jsonArrayOfUsers[i].username in document.querySelector("#" + jsonArrayOfUsers[i].username).src = imageUrl;. Thank you very much again. By the way is there more efficient way of doing this (I'm new to JS)? In terms of my request, I must set the header as I've set up my API that way for Authorization to be required for loading images, but is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are appending insecure text into html is bad...

I would have solved it this way using a simple forEach loop instead of a for loop

```
function parseJSON() {
  var list = $('<ul class="softwares">');
  var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  jsonArrayOfUsers.forEach(function(user) {

    var currentuser = user.username;
    var currentavatar = user.avatar;

    console.log(currentuser);

    var img = $('<img>', {
      id: user.username,
      width: 'auto',
      height: '100px'
    })[0];

    $('<li class ="softwares">').append(
      $('<p>').append(img),
      $('<p>', {text: user.fullName}),
      $('<p>', {text: user.username}),
      $('<p>', {text: user.university}),
      $('<p>', {text: user.userType})
    ).appendTo(list)

    if (jsonArrayOfUsers[i].avatar == null) {

    } else {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "URL TO API" + user.avatar);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.token);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function response(e) {
        img.onload = function() {
          url.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        }
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
  })

  $('.people').append(list);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will understanding this implementation and take your comments onboard. Many thanks. I appreciate it